# A class as an interface in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, model

In a component he uses something like:

```
Method (Obj: MyClass) { .... }
```

It's a shorthand for `Obj = new MyClass` ?

And if in the constructor of `MyClass` there is an argument needed, this should be `Obj = new MyClass (argument)` ? and the `Obj: MyClass`, still works?

Answer (score 1):

> It's a shorthand for `Obj = new MyClass` ?

No, it is not. It only specifies that `Method` receives an argument (`Obj` reference inside the method) of type `MyClass`. It means the argument passed to `Method` must be an instance of `MyClass`.

Example of **correct** usage of `Method`:

```
const ob = new MyClass(); // supose `MyClass` constructor does NOT requieres any argument
Method(ob);
```

Example of **incorrect** usage of `Method`:

```
Method();
```